# reset form on submit button

Tags: javascript, forms, reset

when user submits the form ajax will validate the form and page will not be reloaded. now it is keeping the details user entered.

How can I reset the form once user submitted the form?

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post">
<input name="name" type="text"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

here is my ajax

```
$('#contact-form').on('submit',function(e) {  
$.ajax({
  url:'contact.php', 
  data:$(this).serialize(),
  type:'POST',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
    swal("Thank you", "Message is sent :)", "success");
  },
  error:function(data){
    swal("Sorry", "Failed to send. Please try later :(", "error");
  }
});
e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Can you show your Ajax code?

Comment: `document.getElementById("contact-form").reset()`

Comment: @Johan "page will not be reloaded. now it is keeping the details user entered."

Comment: @rybo111 I posted ajax code

Answer (score 1):

Plain JavaScript

`document.getElementById("contact-form").reset();`

jQuery

`$("form").trigger("reset");` you may need to replace `form` with the id of your form.

another jQuery 
`$("#contact-form")[0].reset();`

What version of Jquery do you use ? As of ver 1.8 success and error are depreciated and [you should use done and fail instead](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: `$("form").trigger("reset");` try that and let us know pls

Comment: or this `$("#contact-form")[0].reset();`

Comment: both are not working for me. could you check my ajax? you might have idea

Comment: Are you putting it within your `success` clause ? Wait ... What version of Jquery do you use ? As of ver 1.8 [success and error are depreciated](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and you should use `done` and `fail` instead.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) now uses `done()` and `fail()` and `success()` is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#contact-form', function(e){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'contact.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data:$(this).serialize()
  })
    .done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      swal("Thank you", "Message is sent :)", "success");
      $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      swal("Sorry", "Failed to send. Please try later :(", "error");
    });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```